# Is it possible to strip the extension before archiving?

Tags: command-line, archiving, 7-zip

I'm not sure about this, but is it possible to save files in an archive under a different name? I'm trying to do this as I'm currently using 7-zip as part of a batch file script to process a bunch of text files together. For example, you have a bunch of files with `(archive)` at the end of the file name, and you'd like that removed before archiving it. Note that I'd only like it removed inside the archive - the original files should still have `(archive)` within the file name. Take this:

```
a (archive).txt
b (archive).txt
c (archive).txt
```

I want to be able to have it inside the archive as the following:

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```

I don't mind if I have to get the filenames inside my script and rename them one by one, but what I'd want to know is whether it's possible using 7-zip or not. I've checked the documentation for such a method, but it seems that it's not possible without creating a temporary directory, just not 100% sure that's the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, you can't do that.  You're either renaming the files before archiving and then renaming them back afterward, or copying/hardlinking the files to a temp folder with the new name and archiving that instead.  You could rename all the files inside the archive after archiving (See 7-Zip's `rn` command), but that'd probably be the slowest option of all.